# Matching multiple date values in R

Tags: r, matching, plyr

I have the following dataframe DF describing people that have worked on a project on certain dates:

```
ID    ProjectName    StartDate 
1       Health        3/1/06 18:20
2       Education     2/1/07 15:30
1       Education     5/3/09 9:00
3       Wellness      4/1/10 12:00
2       Health        6/1/11 14:20
```

The goal is to find  the first project corresponding to each ID. For example the expected output would be as follows:

```
ID    ProjectName    StartDate 
1       Health        3/1/06 18:20
2       Education     2/1/07 15:30
3       Wellness      4/1/10 12:00
```

So far  I have done the following to get the first StartDate for each ID:

```
sub <- ddply(DF, .(ID), summarise, st = min(as.POSIXct(StartDate)));
```

After this, I need to match each row in sub with the original DF and extract the projects corresponding to that ID and StartDate. This can be done in a loop for each row in sub. However, my dataset is very large and I would like to know if there is an efficient way to do this matching and extract this subset from DF.

Comment: `plyr` has been mothballed in favor of `dplyr`, but `DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% first()` works

Answer (score 7):

Here's a `data.table` solution, which ought to be pretty efficient.

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,1,3,2,1), ProjectName=c('Health', 'Education', 'Education', 'Wellness', 'Health', 'Health'),
             StartDate=c('3/1/06 18:20', '2/1/07 15:30', '5/3/09 9:00', '4/1/10 12:00', '6/1/11 14:20', '1/1/06 11:10'))
```

Note that I've modified your data, adding another element at the end, so the dates are no longer sorted.  Thus the output differs.

```
d <- as.data.table(DF)

# Order by StartDate and take the first ID.
# Assumes that your dates are month/day/year.

d[order(as.POSIXct(StartDate, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))][,.SD[1,],by=ID]
##    ID ProjectName    StartDate
## 1:  1      Health 1/1/06 11:10
## 2:  2   Education 2/1/07 15:30
## 3:  3    Wellness 4/1/10 12:00
```

If your dates are already sorted (as in your example), this suffices:

```
d[,.SD[1,],by=ID]
```

Comment: +1 for the reproducible example of OP data and a data.table solution

Answer (score 7):

This is fairly straightforward using `match` because `match` returns:

> a vector of the positions of *first* matches of its first argument in
>   its second

So all you need to do is sort by date, then use `unique` to get one instance of each ID and `match` to find the first position. Thanks to @MatthewLunberg for providing a reproducible example of your data:

```
DF <- DF[ order(as.POSIXct(DF$StartDate, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")) , ]
DF[ match( unique( DF$ID ) , DF$ID ) , ]
#  ID ProjectName    StartDate
#6  1      Health 1/1/06 11:10
#2  2   Education 2/1/07 15:30
#4  3    Wellness 4/1/10 12:00
```

One advantage is that it retains the rownumbers of the original dataframe before resorting. I do not know if this could be useful to you.

Comment: This seems to be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
dat <- data.frame(
    ID=c(1,2,1,3,2), 
    PRJ=c("H","E","E", "W", "H"), 
    START=strptime(
      c(
        "3/1/06 18:20", "2/1/07 15:30", "5/3/09 9:00",
        "4/1/10 12:00","6/1/11 14:20"), 
      "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
    )
min_date <- function(x) {x[which.min(x$START), ]}
s <- split(dat, dat$ID) # split
a <- lapply(s, FUN=min_date) # apply
do.call("rbind", a) # combine
```

which results to

```
  ID PRJ               START
1  1   H 2006-01-03 18:20:00
2  2   E 2007-01-02 15:30:00
3  3   W 2010-01-04 12:00:00
```

However, the order-match solution from @SimonO101 is much faster than this.

Just for the fun of it, here is yet another solution using `sqldf`:

```
sqldf("select * from dat group by ID having START=min(START)")
```

Answer (score 1):

And to round it off, here is a solution based on the `plyr` package. I have added an extra column to make it easier for `textConnection` to read the data.

```
dfProjects = as.data.frame(read.table(textConnection("ID    ProjectName    Date Time 
  1       Health        3/1/06 18:20
  2       Education     2/1/07 15:30
  1       Education     5/3/09 9:00
  3       Wellness      4/1/10 12:00
  2       Health        6/1/11 14:20"), header = TRUE))
ddply(within(dfProjects, dfProjects[order(
  as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")), ]), 
      .(ID), function(dataFrame) dataFrame[1, ])
```