# Pick a value in a column for a given User ID based on two date/time columns in R

Tags: r, matching

I have a data frame that contains `user ID's`, `creation` timestamps, a `date` column, and a status. Each user ID has one creation timestamp, multiple dates, and a different status for each date.

I need to pick the status corresponding to the most recent date prior to (or on) the creation date. My data looks like this:

```
userid    creation               date        status
0001    2014-01-01 03:30:50    2013-01-12    Red
0001    2014-01-01 12:31:12    2011-01-01    Blue
0001    2014-01-01 03:30:50    2014-05-01    Green
0002    2013-12-31 03:30:50    NA            NA
0003    2013-11-11 03:30:50    2013-11-11    Purple
0003    2013-11-11 03:30:50    2012-01-01    Red
```

Both the creation timestamp and date are of `class "POSIXct" "POSIXt"`.

I'm confused as to how to do this. I am tempted to use the package `sqldf`, but even in SQL I'm not exactly sure how I'd query this. There are also NA's in the data, just to make things more interesting.

I found some semi-related posts such as this: [Matching multiple date values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256342/matching-multiple-date-values-in-r?rq=1)  but none that are close enough for me to use as a solution.

An example of the output I'm going for would be:

```
userid    initial_status
0001      Red
0002      NA
0003      Purple
```

where I've just renamed status to initial_status (though this isn't necessary -- it could just be called status).

The closest I've come... which is clearly wrong in more than one way... was

`initial_status <- sqldf("select distinct user_id, status as initial_status, date from x where date <= creation group by user_id")`

I would've used `max(date)` instead of `date` in that `sqldf` query, but when I do that it changes the date stamps to some weird, unintuitive numbers (perhaps that's because it's has to change the class to `numberic` to use `max`).

Comment: Can you include an example of your desired output based on the table provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source :

```
dat<-"userid    creation    date    status
0001    2014-01-01 03:30:50    2013-01-12    Red
0001    2014-01-01 12:31:12    2011-01-01    Blue
0001    2014-01-01 03:30:50    2014-05-01    Green
0002    2013-12-31 03:30:50    NA    NA
0003    2013-11-11 03:30:50    2013-11-11    Purple
0003    2013-11-11 03:30:50    2012-01-01    Red"
dat<-gsub(pattern = '\\s{4}',',',dat)
dat<-read.table(textConnection(dat),sep = ",",header = T)
dat$creation <-as.POSIXct(dat$creation)
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date)
```

With data.table, keeping NA in date as the highest value.

```
library(data.table)
# convert to data.table
dat<-as.data.table(dat)
# sort and index
setkey(dat,userid,date,creation)
# ask for the status which have the max date, by userid.
dat2<-dat[date<creation | is.na(date)][,list(statusOut=
                                               if(anyNA(date)){'noValue'
                                               }else{
                                                 as.character(.SD[which.max(date)]$status)
                                               }
                                             ),by='userid']
```

Output

```
   userid statusOut
1:      1       Red
2:      2   noValue
3:      3    Purple
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the solution as it contains all of the necessary logic. I appreciate your help and will implement this.

Comment: De nada. If something doesn't work as expected, don't hesitate to ask for more help : I did not have access to all your data, and this solution may not be optimal in some case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your data is in a dataframe called `df`:

```
library(lubridate)
df$creation <- ymd_hms(df$creation)  # convert to date-time
df$date <- ymd(df$date)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%  # group by userid
  filter(date <= creation) %>%  # filter by date prior to (or on) creation
  filter(row_number(creation) == 1) %>%  # filter by min creation (see ?row_number)
  select(userid, initial_status = status) # select status variable and rename
```

Comment: Thanks. I can almost take what you have here and get to my solution by building on it, but @fxi seems to have a solution so I will mark his as the correct answer. This is using row number of creation, but creation is the same on each row for a given user ID and I needed it to find the min(date) thats <= creation, which is somewhat different than this. I like that you're using dplyr though; I know that's an extremely powerful tool.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you needed.

Comment: I updated my answer; however, it filters out user `0002` because (s)he doesn't have a date prior to creation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great solution now. I will upvote it.